# Running/Jogging Behavior/Activity Datasets (Amateur Runners Preferred)?

Tags: data-request

Does anyone know of open data sets about running behaviour/running activity? I'd love to find somewhere there are histories for individual runners, but even data about large numbers of runners (distance, pace, location, you name it) would be interesting. I would prefer the data to be about amateurs runners if that is possible. I haven't found anything yet, but I'm not an expert in this field

Comment: Could you please post your own self-answer with the Endomondo tricks you have found? That would be useful for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, sharing is caring

Comment: @sunny, I did try the nikita script on Ruby and try to replicate the script in R, but did not manage to download a thing. Could you please advice in how you did it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARRS - the Association of Road Runner Statisticians seems like the best place for you to start; there's a lot of data that sounds to me to be exactly what you want.
https://arrs.run/

IAAF, the international association of athletics federations has some interesting data too. here's one example for road running marathon records for senior men outdoor:
http://www.iaaf.org/records/by-discipline/road-running/marathon/outdoor/men

Comment: ARRS seems wonderful! It "focuses on elite distance running at distances 3000m and longer". IAAF is about about world (and per-continent) records.

Comment: "the ARRS database which has more than 900,000 performances from more than 160,000 races by more than 35,000 elite distance runners world-wide"

Comment: @albert Thanks a lot for these suggestions. I am more looking for information about amateur runners, which I should have specified in my data request. I know there was an Endomondo data set that was (accidentally?) available, but I don't think it's still available and I don't think it was ever purposely available (only know of its existence from this blog post: http://barsukov.net/programming/2014/07/26/endomondo-code/)

Comment: @sunny np, i edited the question to reflect your desired datasets

Comment: do you have your own personal endomondo account/data....there doesn't seem like much to this, except getting access to people's data.....

Comment: @albert thanks for the update! I also got more instructions on accessing public endomondo profiles like this: https://www.endomondo.com/workouts/ + 9 digits. Note that not all combos work. Also it seems only possible to extract from the json in the HTML source code 1 route. I tried loading other routes, but it seems like it's done with an ajax-style query that shows nothing in the source code. Any ideas folks?

Comment: need more info....can u share the data? or url?

Answer (score 0):

OSM hosts GPS traces for various activities. If you find a couple of frequent uploaders, you can then get a history. This would be more likely for jogging, rather than timed races.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces

and for example these tags (**WATCH OUT:** tags are case sensitive)

https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces?tag=Jog

https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces/tag/Run

https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces/tag/run

---

Bulk GPS traces are here: https://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/

and more info: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/61910/downloading-gpx-traces-over-a-specific-area

---

[image]

[image]